# Is there an iterative way to create tk.Frames and configure them?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Right now I have:

```
# create window frames
    self.f1 = tk.Frame(self.root)
    self.f2 = tk.Frame(self.root)
    self.f3 = tk.Frame(self.root)
    self.f4 = tk.Frame(self.root)
    self.f5 = tk.Frame(self.root)
    self.f6 = tk.Frame(self.root)

# place frames on window
    for f in (self.f1, self.f2, self.f3, self.f4, self.f5, self.f6):
        f.configure(bg="white")
        f.configure(width=self.width, height=self.height, bg="white")
        f.place(x=0, y=0)
```

I am going to be adding a lot more frames. I was wondering if there was an iterative way to create all the frames, as well as place them in the windows and configure them, without having to type "self.f7, self.f8, self.f9" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add every new `Frame` to the list and then iterate over list.

```
frames = []

self.f1 = tk.Frame(self.root)
frames.append(self.f1)
# Do that for all frames

for f in frames:
    f.configure(bg="white")
    f.configure(width=self.width, height=self.height, bg="white")
    f.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Edit to answer the comment:

Create a method for that:

```
def add_frames(self, how_many_frames):
    for i in range(how_many_frames):
        f = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.frames[i] = f
        f.configure(bg="white")
        f.configure(width=self.width, height=self.height, bg="white")
        f.place(x=0, y=0)
```

You also need to have `self.frames = dict()` initialised in `__init__` method. Now call `add_frames(30)` to create 30 frames, store then in dictionary under `self.frames` and configure them at the same time.

Comment: But wouldn't I still need to declare each "Frame" object before appending it? Is there a way I can just input an integer, say 30, and have it automatically populate the list with self.f1, self.f2, self.f3?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Nearly! How would I name them with the convention f1, f2, f3 etc? Do I store those names as keys in the dictionary? (or in other words, how would access them individually? Would I have to use "self.frames[1]", "self.frames[2]", "self.frames[3]", etc?

Comment: As you can see in my example `self.frames[i] = f` , frames are stored in a dictionary, where the key is just a number (in that case numbers from 0 to 29, since I created 30 frames). You can have something like `self.frames["f"+str(i+1)] = f` to have keys like `f1, f2` etc.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks! I was trying to figure out the same thing but I forgot the "str( )"

Comment: You could also use a list comprehension to initialize the frames before configuration: `frames = [tk.Frame(self.root) for _ in range(whatever)]`